# Fragment - using AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-fragments

In a Fragment class I am trying to call an AsyncTask class where in doInBackground() I am trying to fetch Currentlocation and to set to the TextView.

But when i am trying to do this it showing error bellow,

```
E/AndroidRuntime(645): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException:com.example.MainFragmentActivity
```

from my MainFragmentActivity which extends FragmentActivity, I am setting an adapter called FragmentPagerAdapter and within this adapter from `override getItem()` I am calling that fragment like bellow,

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    if (position == 0) {
        Log.i(TAG, "before return in adapter postion 0");
        return ViewPageFragment.newInstance(CONTENT[position % CONTENT.length], context);
    }
}
```

Here is my code,
http://pastebin.com/gykkETJV

How can i solve this?

stacktrace:

```
 E/ViewPageFragment(420): java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.MainFragmentActivity
 E/ViewPageFragment(420): com.example.ViewPageFragment$LocationTask.doInBackground(ViewPageFragment.java:145)
 E/ViewPageFragment(420): com.example.ViewPageFragment$LocationTask.doInBackground(ViewPageFragment.java:1)
 E/ViewPageFragment(420): android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
 E/ViewPageFragment(420): java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
 E/ViewPageFragment(420): java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
 E/ViewPageFragment(420): java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
 E/ViewPageFragment(420): java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
```

Comment: Could you post a bit more of your stacktrace?

Comment: How can i get stacktrace

Comment: All right. Now tell us what is on line 145 in `ViewPageFragment`?

Comment: locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1000, 10, (LocationListener)context);

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as you get a `ClassCastException` and line 145 of your ViewPageFragment is:

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1000, 10, (LocationListener)context);
```

the thing that causes the error is probably that your `context` does not extend/implement `LocationListener`.

Since I expect that `ViewPageFragment` extends `Fragment` you could use `getActivity()` instead of `context` as the last parameter. Remember that if you do, the `Activity` that instantiates the `ViewPageFragment` must extend/implement `LocationListener`.